# Sklearn, gridsearch: how to print out progress during the execution?

Tags: python, logging, scikit-learn

I am using `GridSearch` from `sklearn` to optimize parameters of the classifier. There is a lot of data, so the whole process of optimization takes a while: more than a day. I would like to watch the performance of the already-tried combinations of parameters during the execution. Is it possible?

Comment: How about trying it on less data to get a feel for the right parameter range in shorter evaluation cycles. And then get a feel for whether your choice of parameters on a reduced set scales properly. That depends on your estimator, which you are not naming us.

Comment: That sounds sensible, thanks. I am using wrapper around Vowpal Wabbit.

Comment: Andreas,

verbose : integer
Controls the verbosity: the higher, the more messages.

It does not say it clearly.

Comment: The other part of the story, which I do not know if it was asked, is that you can get a lot of warning statements as well if your process takes a day.  The "verbose" setting will not filter these and this makes monitoring the progress still difficult.  Would there be an approach which also suppresses these warning messages?

Answer (score 171, accepted):

Set the `verbose` parameter in `GridSearchCV` to a positive number (the greater the number the more detail you will get). For instance:

```
GridSearchCV(clf, param_grid, cv=cv, scoring='accuracy', verbose=10)
```

Comment: Just to add: if you are using IPython Notebook, the output is in the IPython terminal window, not in the interactive session.

Comment: What is the actual highest meaningful value of this parameter? Docs mention only "the higher, the more messages.". So, how high can we go and still get more messages?

Comment: As Arturo said below, "verbose=2 is a great choice for most of the practices. It will return one line per parameter set (including CV)"

Comment: On my system, I had to set `n_jobs=1` (default), or no message was shown on JupyterLab.

Comment: @Daddy32 did you find out which one was the highest?

Comment: No, but per [current documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html), it seems any value >3 is currently equivalent. Haven't time to confirm this in the sources.

Comment: Highest param is verbose=3, which is great, bc it gives the params tested in that batch and the most importantly, the score for that specific set of params, as it progresses.  Maybe 10 was a setting way back in 2014, lol, but not going to do anything more than 3 these days.

Comment: Why has this answer still not been edited replacing `verbose=10` with `verbose=3`? I get "There are too many pending edits on Stack Overflow".

Comment: `verbose=3` being the max is outdated. I only get the current and the total number of runs reported starting at exactly `verbose=10` with `GridSearchCV` in `scikit-learn == 1.2.2`. Looks like `[CV 5/5; 3/240]` then - quite useful.

Answer (score 39):

I would just like to complement [DavidS's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24144654/948768)

To give you an idea, for a very simple case, this is how it looks with `verbose=1`:

```
Fitting 10 folds for each of 1 candidates, totalling 10 fits
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Using backend SequentialBackend with 1 concurrent workers.
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done  10 out of  10 | elapsed:  1.2min finished
```

And this is how it looks with `verbose=10`:

```
Fitting 10 folds for each of 1 candidates, totalling 10 fits
[CV] booster=gblinear, learning_rate=0.0001, max_depth=3, n_estimator=100, subsample=0.1 
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Using backend SequentialBackend with 1 concurrent workers.
[CV]  booster=gblinear, learning_rate=0.0001, max_depth=3, n_estimator=100, subsample=0.1, score=0.637, total=   7.1s
[CV] booster=gblinear, learning_rate=0.0001, max_depth=3, n_estimator=100, subsample=0.1 
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   1 out of   1 | elapsed:    7.0s remaining:    0.0s
[CV]  booster=gblinear, learning_rate=0.0001, max_depth=3, n_estimator=100, subsample=0.1, score=0.630, total=   6.5s
[CV] booster=gblinear, learning_rate=0.0001, max_depth=3, n_estimator=100, subsample=0.1 
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   2 out of   2 | elapsed:   13.5s remaining:    0.0s
[CV]  booster=gblinear, learning_rate=0.0001, max_depth=3, n_estimator=100, subsample=0.1, score=0.637, total=   6.5s
[CV] booster=gblinear, learning_rate=0.0001, max_depth=3, n_estimator=100, subsample=0.1 
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   3 out of   3 | elapsed:   20.0s remaining:    0.0s
[CV]  booster=gblinear, learning_rate=0.0001, max_depth=3, n_estimator=100, subsample=0.1, score=0.637, total=   6.7s
[CV] booster=gblinear, learning_rate=0.0001, max_depth=3, n_estimator=100, subsample=0.1 
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   4 out of   4 | elapsed:   26.7s remaining:    0.0s
[CV]  booster=gblinear, learning_rate=0.0001, max_depth=3, n_estimator=100, subsample=0.1, score=0.632, total=   7.9s
[CV] booster=gblinear, learning_rate=0.0001, max_depth=3, n_estimator=100, subsample=0.1 
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   5 out of   5 | elapsed:   34.7s remaining:    0.0s
[CV]  booster=gblinear, learning_rate=0.0001, max_depth=3, n_estimator=100, subsample=0.1, score=0.622, total=   6.9s
[CV] booster=gblinear, learning_rate=0.0001, max_depth=3, n_estimator=100, subsample=0.1 
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   6 out of   6 | elapsed:   41.6s remaining:    0.0s
[CV]  booster=gblinear, learning_rate=0.0001, max_depth=3, n_estimator=100, subsample=0.1, score=0.627, total=   7.1s
[CV] booster=gblinear, learning_rate=0.0001, max_depth=3, n_estimator=100, subsample=0.1 
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   7 out of   7 | elapsed:   48.7s remaining:    0.0s
[CV]  booster=gblinear, learning_rate=0.0001, max_depth=3, n_estimator=100, subsample=0.1, score=0.628, total=   7.2s
[CV] booster=gblinear, learning_rate=0.0001, max_depth=3, n_estimator=100, subsample=0.1 
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   8 out of   8 | elapsed:   55.9s remaining:    0.0s
[CV]  booster=gblinear, learning_rate=0.0001, max_depth=3, n_estimator=100, subsample=0.1, score=0.640, total=   6.6s
[CV] booster=gblinear, learning_rate=0.0001, max_depth=3, n_estimator=100, subsample=0.1 
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   9 out of   9 | elapsed:  1.0min remaining:    0.0s
[CV]  booster=gblinear, learning_rate=0.0001, max_depth=3, n_estimator=100, subsample=0.1, score=0.629, total=   6.6s
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done  10 out of  10 | elapsed:  1.2min finished
```

In my case, `verbose=1` does the trick.

Comment: In my opinion, `verbose=2` is a great choice for most of the practices. It will return one line per parameter set (including CV).

Answer (score 15):

Check out  [the GridSearchCVProgressBar](https://pactools.github.io/auto_examples/plot_grid_search.html?highlight=gridsearchcvprogressbar)

Just found it right now and I'm using it.  Very into it:

```
In [1]: GridSearchCVProgressBar
Out[1]: pactools.grid_search.GridSearchCVProgressBar

In [2]:

In [2]: ??GridSearchCVProgressBar
Init signature: GridSearchCVProgressBar(estimator, param_grid, scoring=None, fit_params=None, n_jobs=1, iid=True, refit=True, cv=None, verbose=0, pre_dispatch='2*n_jobs', error_score='raise', return_train_score='warn')
Source:
class GridSearchCVProgressBar(model_selection.GridSearchCV):
    """Monkey patch Parallel to have a progress bar during grid search"""

    def _get_param_iterator(self):
        """Return ParameterGrid instance for the given param_grid"""

        iterator = super(GridSearchCVProgressBar, self)._get_param_iterator()
        iterator = list(iterator)
        n_candidates = len(iterator)

        cv = model_selection._split.check_cv(self.cv, None)
        n_splits = getattr(cv, 'n_splits', 3)
        max_value = n_candidates * n_splits

        class ParallelProgressBar(Parallel):
            def __call__(self, iterable):
                bar = ProgressBar(max_value=max_value, title='GridSearchCV')
                iterable = bar(iterable)
                return super(ParallelProgressBar, self).__call__(iterable)

        # Monkey patch
        model_selection._search.Parallel = ParallelProgressBar

        return iterator
File:           ~/anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pactools/grid_search.py
Type:           ABCMeta

In [3]: ?GridSearchCVProgressBar
Init signature: GridSearchCVProgressBar(estimator, param_grid, scoring=None, fit_params=None, n_jobs=1, iid=True, refit=True, cv=None, verbose=0, pre_dispatch='2*n_jobs', error_score='raise', return_train_score='warn')
Docstring:      Monkey patch Parallel to have a progress bar during grid search
File:           ~/anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pactools/grid_search.py
Type:           ABCMeta
```

Comment: This will only print to std.err and not show up in Spyder or the iPython Notebook

Comment: For the sake of completiness, it doesn't work either on Visual Studio Code :(

Comment: replacing the `bar` with another progress bar like [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) might fix the display.

Answer (score 0):

Quick Workaround : If you are using nb in Chrome, just search for any word in grid search output. Chrome will automatically update the progress as GridSearch returns more output back to nb.

[image: Jupyter Notebook with GridSearch]